# How to know when the server has received the request?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using `AFHTTPClient` to connect to my backend server to upload an image using `multipartFormRequestWithMethod`. I'm testing the request in an iPhone app with the network conditioner using the `Very Bad Network` setting, this means that the request takes much longer than usual.

To avoid showing the activity indicator for ever I cancel the request after 30 seconds. In the very bad network scenario this means that:

1. the request is cancelled before the upload has finished
2. the request is cancelled after the upload has finished but before the request has finished.

In the second case the server has received the information and therefore stores it in the database but the client receives an error (the operation being cancelled) and therefore the user can try to upload the image again later which will result in having the same image twice.

If, I knew when the request has reached the server I could then avoid posting two times the same image.

How can I check if the server has received a request?

Comment: If your app is freezing at all during comms, you're doing it wrong. Use asynchronous requests, not synchronous; blocking the UI gives a bad user experience.

Comment: @occulus, sorry I explained my self wrong. The app doesn't freeze it shows an activity indicator which blocks the app. My request is done asynchronously.

Comment: Doesn't every HTTP request result in an HTTP response?  Why isn't that enough?

Comment: @trojanfoe, whats happening is that the server receives the request but the client timeout cancels que request operation before the response is received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is only one way to know if the server has completed a previous request, ask the server if it has the content.

Before making the second PUT/POST, make a [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request for the URL you expect the image to be at to see if it exists.

Comment: It does require an additional request to the server but this will work most of the time. (Due to the bad connection the `HEAD` request could also fail)

Comment: @eliocs The client knows if the request completed successfully. HEAD is both [idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and small. While you have reachability repeat making HEAD requests until a successful completion.

Comment: @eliocs As to the additional request: HEAD is both small and server side cacheable. This should keep bandwidth and server overhead small. In addition, this would only be for error handling a failed PUT/POST request. Hopefully you don't have lots of clients generating errors.